# Fetching JSON response and display in HTML elements

Tags: javascript, json, graphql

I am trying to fetch JSON response and display them in my pre-set HTML elements. I am using graphql (provided by datocms).

The API explorer shows for my model:

```
query MyQuery {
  allNews {
    id
    newsTitle
    newsExcerpt
    newsContent
    newsCategory
  }
}
```

Returns:

```
{
  "data": {
    "allNews": [
      {
        "id": "21003677",
        "newsTitle": "The amazing news",
        "newsExcerpt": "The amazing news to waste your afternoon.",
        "newsContent": "\nThe amazing news is unlike other news to waste your afternoon. It indeed wastes your afternoon in a way unimaginable, never before achieved.\n\nThe News consist of fake news and Trumpian staple conspiracies. ",
        "newsCategory": "News"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The fetch:

```
const token = 'the_token_here';
fetch(
  'https://graphql.datocms.com/',
  {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query: '{ allNews { newsTitle } }'
    }),
  }
)
.then(res => res.json())
.then((res) => {
  console.log(res.data)
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

When the static HTML page is loaded, I want to display JSON response in HTML pre-set elements:

```
<h4 class="news--title">$(newsTitle.name)</h4>
<div class="news--description">${newsContent.name}</div>
```

Is it possible using vanilla javascript, and how?

Also, if the response is more than one (say, 10 responses) and I have like four of those element groups, could four JSON responses (based on four biggest ID numbers) be iterated to four HTML elements, and how?

Sorry if the question is dumb or has been asked and answered elsewhere. I am beginning to learn javascript and have never used API calls/JSON before.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand your question, but if you just want to set the content of the elements, try this:

```js
// other code here
const exampleData = { title: "Hello", content: "This is the content" };
document.querySelector(".news--title").innerHTML = exampleData.title;
document.querySelector(".news--description").innerHTML = exampleData.content;
```

```html
<h4 class="news--title"></h4>
<div class="news--description"></div>
```

document.querySelector is a function that will return the first element found with the CSS query.

If you have multiple "news", you can just iterate over them and do the same thing with all of them.

Comment: What should I do to make the JSON response in res.json into this? --> const exampleData = { title: "Hello", content: "This is the content" };
The point for fetching the JSON response is so that I can use the response into the HTML elements automatically.

Comment: I still don't understand it really, if I'm correct, replace the `exampleData` where `innerHTML` is assigned to the object where your data is in.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for template literals. You can have a text like this:

```
var myText = `This is a trivially simple template literal`;
```

or this:

```
var myParam = "great";
var myText2 = `I have a ${myParam} day!`;
```

This will evaluate to "I have a great day!".

Now, if you want to create a template, you can do it like this:

```
function myTemplate(titleName, titleContent) {
    return `
        <h4 class="news--title">${titleName}</h4>
        <div class="news--description">${titleContent}</div>
    `;
}
```

Assuming that you have many such items to generate, you can do something like this:

```
var items = [
    {titleName: 'a', titleContent: 'b'},
    {titleName: 'c', titcleContent: 'd'},
    //...
];
var myTemplates = [];
for (let item of items) myTemplates.push(myTemplate[item.titleName, item.titleContent]);
myContainer.innerHTML = myTemplates.join("");
```

Fetching JSON via a request is also possible with vanilla JS, you have plenty of sources to read from. Example: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp

You can even implement something that will help you in sending requests instead of dealing with Javascript's vanilla support, like:

```
function sendRequest(type, url, callback, async, params) {
    if (async !== false) async = true;
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    console.log(callback);
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = callback;
    xhttp.open(type, url, async);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send(params);
}
```